# How to use hist() in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I read the data into a DataFrame and called it data. I have the following query in python:

```
new_data=data[data["gender"]=="male"].groupby('age').city.nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

now I want to create its histogram using

`new_data.hist()`

which would be something like following:

[image]

I want to do 2 things:

1. I want to show the `bin` ranges, for example for the first bin I want to see something like 20 and 28 (I'm guessing from the picture)
2. I want to add labels to the Axes. so I want on x-axis show age, and y-axis number of ages.

another question: how can I tell hist I want the bins to be in some specific ranges? lets say I want the first bin to be between 20 and 25 , the second from 25 to 35 and so on.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can manually define your bins. Or another common way is to use `np.arange()`. But in your case I guess you want some non-linear bin range. You can also do the same thing on `xticks` and `yticks`.

```
import matlibplot.pyplot as plt
bins_range = np.array([20, 25, 36, 44, 52, 60, 68, 76])
hist_plot = plt.hist(new_data, bins=bins_range)
major_ticks = np.array([20, 25, 36, 44, 52, 60, 68, 76])
plt.xticks(major_ticks)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I change the above figure to show the range of the bins?